# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = " ... JavaScript/HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm trying to implement a simple Highchart into an HTML page. It's got to the point where I've literally just copy and pasted the example from Highcharts to my code to at least get it to work, but no luck... I keep getting the error:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ="

On line 261. I've attached my code below and my  where I include JQuery/Highcharts. Please help I have no idea why this isn't working!!

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<!-- Beginning of Highcharts -->
<script>
  $(document).ready({
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ 
    $(function () { 
      $('highchart').highcharts({
        chart: {
          type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [1, 0, 4]
                      }, {
          name: 'John',
          data: [5, 7, 3]
          }]
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you just stick a `document.ready` function inside the `Higcharts.Chart` function ?

Comment: even you dont have proper selector `$('highchart')` what is it class/id?

Comment: @Jai this is the class/id  <div id="highchart" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

Comment: @user3146758 then try this `$('#highchart')`, notice `#` which denotes id and `.` denotes the class, and you can try this with the answer you have with your post.

Comment: The `{` in `$(document).ready({` starts an object literal. Object literals have the form `{key: value, key: value, ...}`. You cannot have arbitrary assignments inside such a literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready()
```

expects a function to be passed as a parameter. you are giving it an assignment.

i think you do not need

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
```

at all.

remove this and try.

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)

actually i think your code will be ok with just this:

```
<script>
    $(function () { 
          $('#highchart').highcharts({
            chart: {
              type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
              text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
              categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
              title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
              }
            },
            series: [{
              name: 'Jane',
              data: [1, 0, 4]
                          }, {
              name: 'John',
              data: [5, 7, 3]
              }]
            });
          });
</script>
```

Comment: I had this code earlier but ran into this issue...                       Uncaught Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13 highcharts.js:16
ka highcharts.js:16
yb.getContainer highcharts.js:192
yb.firstRender highcharts.js:205
yb.init highcharts.js:179
yb highcharts.js:19
a.fn.highcharts highcharts.js:26
(anonymous function) (index):261
k jquery.min.js:2
l.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
p.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
D

Comment: you are not passing a valid id, you are using $('highchart') while it should be $('#highchart') where highchart is the id of the div where you want to display the chart